# How the Return Value for this Merge Sort Works?

Tags: java, return-value, mergesort

In a computer science class, this example for a merge sort came up. How does the array "array1" get changed in the end, even though the "mergeSort()" function does not return anything? I am baffled. I asked my teacher, but he is not sure.

Can anyone else help me with this? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array1 = {5, 3, 4, 1, 6, 2};
        int[] array2 = {5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 3, 1, 2};

        System.out.print("First array: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        // System.out.print("Second array: ");
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
        System.out.println();

        // sort first array
        mergeSort(array1);
        // sort second array
        // mergeSort(array2);

        System.out.print("First array sorted: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
        // System.out.print("Second array sorted: ");
        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
    }

    /*
     * Merge sort takes in an array and returns the same array, sorted.
     */
    public static void mergeSort(int[] arr) 
    {
        int[] temp = new int[arr.length];
        mergeSortHelper(arr, 0, arr.length - 1, temp);
    }

    public static void mergeSortHelper(int[] arr, int from, int to, int[] temp)
    {
        // If the array length is greater than 1
        if(to - from >= 1)
        {
            int mid = (from + to) / 2;
            mergeSortHelper(arr, from, mid, temp);
            mergeSortHelper(arr, mid + 1, to, temp);
            merge(arr, from, mid, to, temp);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int[] arr, int from, int mid, int to, int[] temp) 
    {
        int i = from;       // track left array position
        int j = mid + 1;    // track right array position
        int k = from;       // track temp position

        while(i <= mid && j <= to)
        {
            // If the element in the left subarray is less
            // than the element in the right subarray it 
            // is next in the merged list
            if(arr[i] < arr[j])
            {
                temp[k] = arr[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[k] = arr[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        // We may have missed elements from either list
        while(i <= mid)
        {
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while(j <= to)
        {
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        // Copy over from temp to elements
        for(k = from; k <= to; k++)
        {
            arr[k] = temp[k];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of teacher is that?

Comment: Why would a teacher teach you how mergesort is implemented without even explaining how method calls work and what happens to arguments which are of primitive types or reference types?

Comment: If your teacher doesn't know why I suggest you change to a different section of the class taught by someone else.

Comment: Please carefully read [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/18157).  Java is pass-by-value, but reference types are passed by passing a reference to the actual object.  This includes arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the late response, I did not see any emails about this post so I thought no one had responded.

I should clarify: my teacher is supposed to teach us Java, which he does some, but also he likes to focus a lot on news about programming, like "there is a security flaw apple found recently," etc. He is also very laid back, and does not know how to keep the class in line, and so basically every single person in my class but me (I am the only person interested in the class) watches videos and plays games during class and never does any homework. My teacher is so laid back that he does not punish anyone, so I end up being the only person who knows anything about java.

He had us go do something on code HS for AP Java, but I was the only person to really do it on time, so I had nothing to do but look around different coding techniques on the website while my teacher waited for my classmates to do something for several classes. As I was looking around, I saw a little section on the mergesort and was given this example by code HS. That is when I asked my teacher about it. I guess he is so out of practice from never teaching very much Java that he did not know the answer. Heck, he did not even remember what an abstract class was.

He is the only teacher on the subject at my school. I think he is going to be a little more strict next year though, because from what I have heard his lower-level computer science class has actually been doing stuff. Maybe I have given him a little bit of hope that there are students out there that actually care about computer science.

Answer (score 0):

`mergeSort()` calls `mergeSortHelper()` which calls `merge()`.

`merge()` changes the array on the line `arr[k] = temp[k];`

Therefore, `mergeSort()` does actually modify the array, although it does so by calling other methods which modify the array.